# show callout on mouse hover of linkbutton

Tags: asp.net

HI Guys, I have a problem that I want to show designer callouts on mouseover of linkbutton in c# asp.net. I have searched it on the web but I only get validator callout example of Ajax but I want only callout on every control. How it can be possible? Please suggest me the right result. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Agreed JQuery is a good idea. If you just need a simple hover-over text, try the ToolTip property of the Link Button.